# How to control the UAC "Change when these notifications appear" slider from command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

Is it possible to set the value of the dialog below from the command line or powershell?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning:** User Account Control is a security feature which controls user access boundary of unprivileged users aka. non-admin. Messing with registries associated with UAC may cause system instability. Backup registry settings before making any change. Use these with caution.

Here are the list of registry value changes (using [this method](https://superuser.com/a/1338728/726810)) for all the four options in UAC prompt:

1. Always notify

```ini
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:1
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:2
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:1
```

2. Notify me only when apps try to make changes to my computer (default)

```ini
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:1
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:5
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:1
```

3. Notify me only when apps try to make changes to my computer (do not dim my desktop)

```ini
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:1
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:5
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:0
```

4. Never notify me

```ini
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:1
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:0
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:0
```

To change the values from Command Line use [`reg.exe` commands](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) in Command Prompt or in any shell or in any terminal. For example, the fourth change will be as follows:

```bat
set X=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
reg.exe add %X% /V "EnableLUA" /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F
reg.exe add %X% /V "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F
reg.exe add %X% /V "PromptOnSecureDesktop" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F
```